# Case-When an order table were a column references different opt-put

Tags: sql, select, case-when

We have an `Order` table. The `Object_Id` column in is the key for either an organisation id or an individual id. The `object_name` column in the `Order` table identifies whether the `Object_id` is either an organisation or a contact.

I'm looking to query the data so that I can output an `Organisation.name` or a contact name (`concat(contact.forname, " ", contact.surname)`) where applicable.

I believe I need a `Case` statement for this. Below is the SQL I have been testing with:

```
select 
  object_name,
  object_id
  case when Order.object_name = 'contact' 
    then Order.object_id = Contact.id
  else Order.object_name ='organisation' 
    then Order.object_id = Organisation.name 
  end as object_test,
from Order    
  join Contact on Order.object_id = Contact.id
  join Organisation on Order.object_id = Organisation.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax issues on your code. Should be something like:

```
select 
object_name,
object_id,

 case when Order.object_name ='contact' then Contact.id
    when Order.object_name ='organisation' then Organisation.name 
else 'default_value' end as object_test,

    from Order

    join Contact on Order.object_id = Contact.id
    join Organisation on Order.object_id = Organisation.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. When `Order.object_name ='contact'` you could just simply use `concat(contact.forname, " ", contact.surname)`. After `then` you can simply specify what an sql engine should pick.

```
select 
  object_name,
  object_id,
  case 
    when Order.object_name = 'contact' then concat(contact.forname, " ", contact.surname)
    when Order.object_name ='organisation' then  Organisation.name 
  end as object_test
from Order    
  join Contact on Order.object_id = Contact.id
  join Organisation on Order.object_id = Organisation.id
```

Comment: Thanks both. Yeah once Carlos got me to where I needed to be I was able to add in the concat - concat(contact.forname, " ", contact.surname)